# Using AWS CloudFormation estimate-template-cost to get the estimated cost of a live CloudFormation stack

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I'm trying to get the estimated cost for a given stack. e.g.

`aws cloudformation get-template --stack-name MyStack | aws cloudformation estimate-template-cost --template-body -`

The above is returning a `Template format error: unsupported structure.`. I would expect it to accept the template considering it is a valid CF template. Is there a workaround?

Additionally, passing the template itself as a file results in the API returning an error due to the template being too long

`aws cloudformation get-template --stack-name MyStack > template.yml && aws cloudformation estimate-template-cost --template-body file://template.yml`

error:

`' at 'templateBody' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must have length less than or equal to 51200`

I suppose the template could be manually edited to remove the longer parts but that makes it very manual and I'm looking for a more straight forward way to get an estimated cost.

Answer (score 4):

The maximum size of a template body that you can pass in a CreateStack, UpdateStack, or ValidateTemplate request is 51,200 bytes.

To use a larger template body, do one of the following:

- upload the template to an Amazon S3 bucket, or
- separate your template into multiple templates by using nested stacks